# Lombok getters/setters are not visible from my annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I did custom implementation of `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` and it work.
But my processor do not found getters, setters and constructors which generated by Lombok.

Here my propceesor(do I need to create minimal example?):
https://github.com/hohserg1/ElegantNetworking/blob/1.12.2-annotation-processor/src/main/java/hohserg/elegant/networking/annotation/processor/ElegantPacketProcessor.java#L62

Example class:

```java
ElegantPacket //my
@Value //lombok
public class Test implements ClientToServerPacket {
    int some; //it visible
    //int getSome() //generated by Lombok, it invisible
    //public Test(int some) //generated by Lombok, it invisible
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve this by using `annotationProcessor` of gradle dependency configuration:

```
dependencies {
    //gradle 4.6+
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8', "io.gitlab.hohserg.elegant.networking:annotation-processor:2.8"
    ...
}
```

Also not all lombok changes visible from my annotation processor still. Changes of fields access modifiers is not visible, but it can be determine from lombok annotations. As example, @Value makes package-private fields to private.

Also plugin apt may be used on gradle less that 4.6

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.9'
    }
}
dependencies {
    apt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8', "io.gitlab.hohserg.elegant.networking:annotation-processor:2.7"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to run both Lombok and another annotation processor, then you should delombok your code and run your annotation processor on the result.

This is what the [Checker Framework Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/kelloggm/checkerframework-gradle-plugin#lombok-compatibility) does, as explained in the [Checker Framework Manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#lombok-typechecking).

**Explanation:**
Most annotation processors either produce output (say, issue warnings) or generate new classes.  Lombok is an annotation processor that modifies existing code.  It does so by accessing internal APIs of the `javac` compiler (it also supports `eclipsec`).  These manipulations cause `javac` to emit bytecode that contains Lombok's changes to your classes.  However, those changes are invisible to earlier phases of the compiler, notably your annotation processor.  Another way of saying all this is that Lombok does not play well with other annotation processors.